# idiom and conjunctions

Tags: idioms, conjunctions

I'd like to ask you about 'seeing that'

I wonder if I can use it like this.

'I think they should have made efforts. seeing that, that was their duties.'

(not 'seeing that that was their duties, I think they should have made efforts.'

Answer (score 1):

The "seeing that" part is correct, but you would not put a comma between the two thats. Also, it should be "should have made AN effort" and "that was their duty" (singular duty).

So it would be :
"I think they should have made an effort, seeing that that was their duty.

Comment: Or: seeing that those were their duties.